# ORA-03113 end of file communication

Tags: oracle, subquery, rownum, ora-03113

I am running a long query(having lot of subqueries) with rownum from VB6 which is giving ORA-03113 end of file on communication after approximately 1 minute. The query run fine from Toad. When the same query is run from VB6 without ROWNUM then query works fine. Also this is parameterised query, if i remove parameters and enter the values directly in query, then also query run fines from vb6.

This query was running fine few days back. Now it is not.

I tried increasing the connection timeout but still i am getting error after 1 minute. Could anyone suggest what could be the problem?

Answer (score 3):

This often indicates that an ORA-00600 internal error has been thrown on the server. Check the alert log and trace files.

Answer (score 1):

ORA-03113 on the client side is one of the oracle catch-all error that is thrown.  You need to see if there is any additional error that accompany that error to give you an idea of the problem.  The problem can be server side if there is an ORA-00600 that accompanies the ORA-03113 with the same sid/serial of the session.   Check the server logs for both the ORA-03113 and any addition error.   If there are no server side error, then the error is  client side.  Check for any network/connection related issue, but since the query works without the rownum network is probably not the cause.   That means its probably a client side bug, now comes the need to enable client side tracing of the connection and see if you can generate a consistent issue and trace that you can then use to raise a case with oracle support to see if there is a bug you can get patch/fixed on the client.